# cannot load such file -- capistrano/cli (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Capistrano deployment tool in my rails application.If i try to run cap commend using Capistrano, i get this error. The error likes below

```
> /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/cli (LoadError)   from
> /home/stllpt010/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /usr/bin/cap:3:in `<main>'
```

How can i fix this problem?